# How can I set up a regression model and choosing likelihood function?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, poisson

I am trying to use a Poisson regression for modeling sports. For this Poisson regression, I have a given linear combination for log(lambda) which is the sum of different variables. Two of the variables are constants, the other two are vectors dependent on home team and away team. I have tried to use statsmodels GenericLikelihoodModel and decided the likelihood function based on log(lambda)=a + b + c + d. This yields not satisfying results, one problem is that all other values except from Coeff when I use fit.summary() are nan. Another problem is that I don't know how to fix the likelihood function such that it becomes log(lambda)=a_i + b_j + c + d.

Really hope to hear from somebody! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: statsmodels has Poisson and other count models available. There is no need to use GenericLikelihoodModel. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/discretemod.html Default for count models is log link, i.e. the prediction (poisson intensity) is `E(y|x) = exp(X b)`

Comment: In regression context, parameters like group specific effects a_i, b_j are usually represented by dummy variables or categorical encoding. You cannot have two constants, c + d, they will not be individually identified, only the sum will be identified.